# Create responsive table using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive

How can I create a responsive table?

The table I want is similar to this one:

[image]

The table must be responsive, so what have to change is the width of the columns.

I think the best solution is to use Flexbox but how?

I try this code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div> <!-- empty cell -->
    <div class="cell">something</div>
    <div class="cell">dog</div>
    <div class="cell">more dogs</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">column2 long title</div>
    <div class="cell">abc</div>
    <div class="cell">a</div>
    <div class="cell">aaaaaaa</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">column 3 tilew</div>
    <div class="cell">bbbb</div>
    <div class="cell">da</div>
    <div class="cell">f</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">something</div>
    <div class="cell">ggggg</div>
    <div class="cell">f</div>
    <div class="cell">cats</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I simply create 4 columns, and each column has the same number of row but, of course, they will not be of the same height.
How can I fix it?

Then, the first cell must be empty

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you consider [css-grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)?

Comment: Actually the best solution **is a table**. No need to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: @fen1x Yes, but I don't know how to use here. Can you have an example?

Comment: @beth There's example in kukkuz' answer below. Also, as Paulie_D said, the _best_ (by which I mean _easiest_) way to show table data is to use `<table>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see *why* you need to use flexbox rather than a table. Anyway you can use CSS Grid layout here just for the sake of *not* using tables - it is easy to set up for the code in the question.

Also using `display: contents` here - note that it is supported in newer browsers - full support explanation [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents).

```css
.container {
  display: grid; /* grid containers */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); /* four columns */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr); /* four rows */
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* in column direction */
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.column {
  display: contents; /* the child elements would be grid items */
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div> <!-- empty cell -->
    <div class="cell">something</div>
    <div class="cell">dog</div>
    <div class="cell">more dogs</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">column2 long title</div>
    <div class="cell">abc</div>
    <div class="cell">a</div>
    <div class="cell">aaaaaaa</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">column 3 tilew</div>
    <div class="cell">bbbb</div>
    <div class="cell">da</div>
    <div class="cell">f</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">something</div>
    <div class="cell">ggggg</div>
    <div class="cell">f</div>
    <div class="cell">cats</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @beth also upvote on the answer if you like it, thank you :)

Comment: This won't work if we add feature like expanding

Answer (score 0):

Here it is!

```css
/* 
Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
*/
table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
/* Zebra striping */
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #eee; 
}
th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
}
td, th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
}



/* 
Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
and also iPads specifically.
*/
@media 
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

 .responsive-table-input-matrix {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;

  &:after {
   clear: both;
   content: '';
   display: block;
   font-size: 0;
   height: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
  }

  tbody {
   display: block;
   overflow-x: auto;
   position: relative;
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: auto;


   tr {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;

    td {
     display: block;
     text-align: center;

     &:first-child {
      text-align: left;
     }
    }
   }
  }

  thead {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 10px;

   &:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
   }

   th:first-of-type {
    height: 1.4em;
   }

   th {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;

    &:first-child {
     text-align: right;
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<table class="responsive-table-input-matrix">
  <thead>
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>Owner</th>
   <th>Group</th>
   <th>Others</th>
   <th>Administrators</th>
   <th>Managers</th>
   <th>Engineers</th>
   <th>Sales</th>
   <th>Employees</th>
   <th>Customers</th>
   <th>Community</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <tr>
   <td>Add</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Edit</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Delete</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Rename</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Move</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```